# Replace dynamic string with notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a html page that has list of `href="<myUrls>"` tags now im using angular so I need to find and replace it to `(click)="redirectTo('myUrls')"` is it possible to do it with notepad++?

Example :

**mypage.html**

```
<a href="home.html" class="myClass1 myClass2">
<a href="myProfile.html" class="myClass3 myClass4>
<a href="aboutUs.html" class="myClass1 myClass2">
<a href="gallery.html" class="myClass3 myClass4>
```

want this code to be replaced as

```
<a (click)="redirectTo('home.html')" class="myClass1 myClass2">
<a (click)="redirectTo('myProfile.html')" class="myClass3 myClass4">
<a (click)="redirectTo('aboutUs.html')" class="myClass1 myClass2">
<a (click)="redirectTo('gallery.html')" class="myClass3 myClass4">
```

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `href="([^"]+)`
- Replace with: `\(click\)="redirectTo\('$1'\)`  Don't forget to escape the parenthesis
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
href="      : literally
(           : start group 1
  [^"]+     : 1 or more any character that is not a quote
)           : end group 1
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<a (click)="redirectTo('home.html')" class="myClass1 myClass2">
<a (click)="redirectTo('myProfile.html')" class="myClass3 myClass4>
<a (click)="redirectTo('aboutUs.html')" class="myClass1 myClass2">
<a (click)="redirectTo('gallery.html')" class="myClass3 myClass4>
```